# Compactly supported functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, compactness, distribution-theory

Given $$g=g(x):\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$$ $g\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support, Is It always possibile to construct $v=v(t,x) \in C^1([0,+\infty)\times\mathbb{R})$ such that $v$ has compact support and $$v(0,x)=g(x)$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: Take any $C^1_c[0,\infty)$ function $h$ with $h(0) = 1$ and set $v(t,x) = g(x)h(t)$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor.  Include  h has compact support.

Comment: @WilliamElliot that's what the subscript c in $C^1_c$ means